# Sprockets cant find asset from rails-assets.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, asset-pipeline, bundler, react-router

I try to install react-router and material-ui on my rails 4 app but I get `Sprockets::FileNotFound` error for react-router and material-ui. I follow instructions from rails-assets.org.

*My Gemfile:*

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-classnames'
  gem 'rails-assets-lodash'
  gem 'rails-assets-react-router'
  gem 'rails-assets-material-ui'
end
```

*application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require lodash
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
//= require classnames
//= require react_ujs
//= require react-router
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And after `bundle` I got this notification on some gems `This component doesn't define main assets in bower.json.`. Thank you for your time and I hope we work this out.

**UPD 1:**

I found kind of a solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446248/using-material-ui-with-react-rails-gem) but I would like to stick to rails-assets.org way if possible.

- ruby    '2.2.0'
- rails   '4.2.3'

Answer (score 0):

Might be easy to forget, but have you restarted your (running) rails server?

Started to use rails-assets yesterday as well and it showed me the exact same problem (Sprockets::FileNotFound).

I restarted the running server in the console and the problem was solved.

Rails 4.2.5
 / Ruby 2.3.